# Syntax for using SAMPLE() function with two or more orderBy expressions

Tags: random, dax, powerpivot

I would like to use the SAMPLE() function in DAX to select random rows from a table. In the documentation the function appears to support multiple OrderBy_Selection parameters but I'm unable to get the syntax right.

I have a table named dCRQRisk with two columns that I would like to order by before selecting the sample rows: RSO, then RISK_LEVEL, both in Ascending order.

//This is the syntax

```
SAMPLE(<n_value>, <table>, <orderBy_expression>, [<order>[, <orderBy_expression>, [<order>]]…])`
```

//This works

```
SAMPLE(31,dCRQRisk, dCRQRisk[RSO],1)
```

//When I try to add the second OrderBy_Expression it does not work

```
SAMPLE(31, dCRQRisk, dCRQRisk[RSO],[1[,dCRQRisk[RISK_LEVEL],[1]]])
```

//This is the error message

> Query(2, 60) Unexpected value for ORDER argument in SAMPLE function.
>   Use 0/FALSE/DESC for descending order or 1/TRUE/ASC for ascending
>   order.

Answer (score 1):

Those brackets are to indicate optional arguments, not part of the syntax.

Try this:

```
SAMPLE(31, dCRQRisk, dCRQRisk[RSO], 1, dCRQRisk[RISK_LEVEL], 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. Unfortunately, this is the error I receive: This formula is invalid or incomplete: 'Calculation error in measure 'dCRQRisk'[ed9ccab3-ed44-4584-b6c9-f7625798d787]: The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value.'.

Comment: A measure can only return a single value but you are asking for 31 rows. What do you intend to do with these rows?

Comment: I'm trying to calculate the proportion each RSO/Risk_Level combination contributes to the whole, then use SAMPLE() to select the correct number of rows. Perhaps there's a way to use COUNTAX to provide arguments to SAMPLE ()